# SOAP , XSL and HTML

Tags: xslt, soap

I'm not new with XML request like payments gateways and others.

However i'm new in SOAP and XSL.

I have this XML returned from a rent-a-car web service:
bluealliance-pt.w4.makeitsimple.pt/teste.xml

i want convert it using XSL to show it in my site.
I tried do that with normal XML without any problem at:
bluealliance-pt.w4.makeitsimple.pt/listar.asp
with these files:
bluealliance-pt.w4.makeitsimple.pt/banco.xml
bluealliance-pt.w4.makeitsimple.pt/visualizar.xsl

But i don't know how to do with SOAP XML, how i find elements and values on it.
Is possible clear some info of xml so i can have a shorter XML ?
What is the way to get info from it ?

Hi only need get values from MultiplePrices1 , 2, 3.. etc..
I need that XSL run all MultiPrices and show then all values of each one.

I will appreciate any help

Comment: I am not sure anyone will be able to help unless you show us some sample source and target XML

Comment: Which platform are you using? Java? .NET?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special in the provided SOAP response, since the elements of interest are in no namespace.

**This simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <table border="1">
     <xsl:apply-templates/>
   </table>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="MultiplePrices">
  <tr>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="MultiplePrices/*[not(*)]">
  <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></td>
  <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the XML document contained at the provided URL** (**http://bluealliance-pt.w4.makeitsimple.pt/teste.xml**), produces a table containing a name-value pair for every child element (with simple content) of `MultiplePrices`.

**You can use this XSLT transformation as a base and put inside it your own code**.